# How to stop the red (infected) turtles from immediately turning gray (recovered/removed)

Tags: netlogo

I'm fairly new to Netlogo and I've been trying to code an epidemic simulation. I have looked at the epidem and virus models available in Netlogo but I still can't seem to figure out my problem. 
So initially a random 10 turtles are infected and turn red, but how can I increase the time of infection so that they have time to infect other turtles and not immediately become gray (removed/recovered)?
Any feedback is appreciated! 
Here's my code:

```
breed [women woman]
breed [men man]
breed [children child]

turtles-own
[ susceptible?
infected?
removed?
infection-length    ;; How long the person has been infected
recovery-time       ;; Time it takes for the patient to recover
nb-infected
nb-recovered ]

to setup

clear-all

create-women 50 
 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set color red + 2
   set removed? false
   set infected? false
   set susceptible? true
   set size 1.5 ]

ask women [ set shape "person"]

create-men 50 
 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set color blue + 1
   set removed? false
   set infected? false
   set susceptible? true
   set size 1.5 ]
ask men [set shape "person"]

create-children 25
 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set color yellow
   set removed? false
   set infected? false
   set susceptible? true
   set size 1 ]
ask children [set shape "person"]

ask n-of 10 turtles
[get-infected]

reset-ticks
end


to go
ask turtles 
[move
 if infected? [infect]
 if infected? [get-removed]
 ]
end

to move 
rt random 100
lt random 100
fd .1 
end


to get-infected
set infected? true
set color red 
end


to infect
ask other turtles-here with [ not infected? and not removed? ]
[ if random-float 100 < infectiousness
  [get-infected] ]
end


to get-removed
if recovery-time < duration
[ifelse random-float 100 < recovery-chance
  [become-removed]
  [die] ]
end

to become-removed
set infected? false
set removed? true
set color gray
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're never telling a sick turtle to increase its duration. Something like:

```
to get-removed

set duration duration + 1

if recovery-time < duration
[ifelse random-float 100 < recovery-chance
  [become-removed]
  [die] ]
end
```

Should help out.